# Alter table date_time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I created a table with the following column:

```
CREATE TABLE PERFORMANCE 
(
    ...
    created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ....
)
```

but it has by default the server regional time setting, I'm doing a `drop table`:  to save with the regional configuration of Colombia, but I could not

```
-- SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '-05:00') 
ALTER TABLE PERFORMANCE ALTER COLUMN created datetime default SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '-05:00');
```

Comment: If you're in a multi timezone environment either use `datetimeoffset` and `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET` or store all your values as UTC (`SYSUTCDATETIME`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should find out the default constraint name by using following

```
sp_help PERFORMANCE
```

When you get this then you should drop it and create it using following queries.
Please note that in my case constraint name is DF__PERFORMAN__creat__4C701D42 but it should be different for you

```
alter table PERFORMANCE drop constraint DF__PERFORMAN__creat__4C701D42 

alter table PERFORMANCE add constraint DF__PERFORMAN__creat__4C701D42 default SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '-05:00') for created
```

After updating the constraint you can verify it by using SP_help which we have executed first.